Should non-expert-shochets’ veal be trusted
According to this answer, there are several issues in Halacha with white veal, however most opinions conclude ruling it kosher. My question is, should we have trust that veal from a non-expert-shochet is kosher, based on rov beheimos  kesheiros, the majority of animals are presumed kosher, or due to the complications with the feed and higher levels of treifot is an expert shochet required?

Can we define expert vs non-expert shochet?  My initial reaction was "anyone who we would define as a non-expert shochet is an amateur and we should not trust his shechita of anything" but perhaps you meant something else by non-expert

In the linked answer, I don't see issues a shochet would have to deal with. The issues mention relate to how the veal was raised, which is not something the shochet would deal with. The treifa issue doesn't appear different from other animals.

I don't see how this is relevant, given that shochtim today tend to work for hechsherim, rather than a local community's rav or a slaughterhouse. Given that most authorities require a separate bodek, this would rely on the bodkim being reliable and knowing what to look for
